# References for Business Calculus with Challenging Problems

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I'm not sure if this is the right community I could ask to, but I'm looking for a reference in business calculus that has challenging problems. The ones that I found so far have easy problems and can be solved within a day. I'm looking for problems that will probably take time to solve and will use a lot of thinking (and not just copy the methods/insert some formulas to solve).

I would appreciate it if someone can recommend to me a reference that I'm looking for.